# My console.log is in the wrong place but I do not understand why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

So my console.log prints as if I am one step behind on my onSubmit calls, but when I check the React web tools on Chrome I see that my state is up to date. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here? I believe it is a misunderstanding up asynchronous and synchronous methods, but could really use a good explanation on this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoInput from './todo-input';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      inputValue: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = {
      title: this.state.inputValue,
      id: Date.now,
      done: false
    };
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: [...prevState.todos, newTodo]
    }));
    this.setState({inputValue: ''});
console.log(this.state.todos);
  }

  render() {
    const mappedTodos = this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => 
      <div key={index}>
        {todo.title}
      </div>
    )

    return (
        <div>
          <TodoInput
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
          {mappedTodos}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It is because console.log is called first before the setState which is not a synchronous action. Instead use a callback function right after setState to see your console log.

Answer (score 1):

This should console log after state update.

```js
this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: [...prevState.todos, newTodo]
    }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.todos)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the setState() is an asynchronous call, so your console.log() is returning the state as if none of your setState() calls were made. However, this can be solved using the setState callback function argument to produce your expected output:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = {
      title: this.state.inputValue,
      id: Date.now,
      done: false
    };
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: [...prevState.todos, newTodo],
      inputValue: ''
    }), () => { console.log(this.state.todos) });
}
```